# Positioning an images outside of the layout

Tags: html, css

I am making a website thats 960px wide but I want images on both sides of the header that you can see if you have a bigger screen.

because I want to keep the site 960px wide I need these extra side images to not be counted by the browser, I can get it to work on the left

see here:

[image]

http://www.wireframebox.com/test/sideimages/index_leftworks.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-color:#096 }

img { border: 0; }

#main { 
    width:960px; 
    height:216px; 
    background-image:url(main.jpg);
    position:relative;
    top:0; margin: 0 auto;
}



#left {
    width:170px;
    height:216px;
    background-image:url(left.jpg);
    float:left;
    left:-170px;
    position:relative;
}

#right {
    width:170px;
    height:216px;
    background-image:url(right.jpg);
    float:right;
    left:170px;
    position:relative;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you make your window thinner the left red image disappears off the site without causing the browser window to get a bottom scroll bar, however when I try and do the same thing to the right side it doesn't work

see here

[image]

http://www.wireframebox.com/test/sideimages/

Code is equal, only `<div id="right"></div>` is missing

the css is in the source.

you can also see it being used on this site to show the date sticking out the left of the page, without impacting the overall sites width

http://www.tequilafish.com/2009/04/22/css-how-to-pin-an-image-to-the-bottom-of-a-div/

why does this work on the left but not the right?

Comment: i inserted images and code. Please think about others reading that with the same problem and your sites being offline :) And please apply the changes :)

Comment: Thanks for doing all that! hopefully somebody can see whats going wrong, also I don't know what you mean by "And please apply the changes"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning an image outside of the layout, without scroll bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731774/positioning-an-image-outside-of-the-layout-without-scroll-bars)

Comment: Why did you repost your previous question? Edit that one

Comment: @russian box - Check my answer it might help you get the concept of how to achieve your desired layout. If i am lagging some where please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the below fiddle for output...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/4/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/4/embedded/result/

see below image -

[image]

Comment: This seem to be it! however if I put content into the content div such as an image with hyperlink on i can't click it. is this something to do with how the divs are stacked?

Comment: i sorted that problem^ this is because i'm new to all this so i playd with putting a  div inside the content div and giving that one a z-index:1; which seemd to make the content clickable! :O

Comment: Thank you Happy Singh! i shall do what you did in that fiddle and set the colum in the - so I don't need to keep telling new stuff to be in the + :)

Comment: OMFG its fantastic approach :D

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you can combine those two images & give in the `background` of body. like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background:#096 url(http://imgur.com/JHXDv.png) no-repeat top center; 
}

#main {
    width:960px;
    height:216px;
    background-image:url(http://www.wireframebox.com/test/sideimages/main.jpg);
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PVWzA/1/

Comment: Thank you for working on this. yes I knew about having one image that spanned the top section but I'm wanting to keep it separate / float other pictures off the sides. what you suggested is a way of doing it but not what I was looking for. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your website page to be 960px wide, then you should change your width of the main image to 960 - 170(left) - 170(right). Changing the width of main.jpg to 620px should fix your issue.

HTH

Comment: I want the side images to not be counted towards the width of the page, it works for the left but not the the right. see my links

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div or image tag that is larger than your center div and make it the child of the center content div.  Also make sure that it's positioning will take it out of the flow(\absolute). If you then add a negative margin you can pull the image outside of the content div without disrupting its placement.

```
 #center div.top{
        width:1200px;
        height:170px;
        margin: 0px -170px;
        position:absolute;

        background:url("randombackground.png") no-repeat;
    }
```

The html will be kinda like this:

```
<div id="center">
<div class="top"></div>
Content content content
</div>
```

Comment: I've played around with this but it doesn't seem to work. Not how I want. 
It puts a div out of the left of my screen than I can't see :S, what I'm trying to do is sit an image on the right of my header, like I did on the left, and have it not add a scroll bar to the bottom of the window when the window is 1300px and under, see these images:

http://www.wireframebox.com/test/sideimages/justleft.jpg
http://www.wireframebox.com/test/sideimages/left_and_right.jpg

Comment: do you just have 2 small images? can you combine them into one that is 1200px wide? then my solution should work... and as for the scrolling thing, you probably will need to wrap the whole page in a div with overflow:hidden; .. maybe using some jQuery or plain javascript to keep its width at 100%