# HTML/CSS design for 100% width horizontal gradient effect

Tags: html, css, gradient, fluid

I'm trying to achieve the effect of having a horizontal gradient stretch the entire width of the browser. Currently, my idea is to have three segments, one to the left which has it's background colour set with CSS to the first colour. This would be followed by the actual gradient which is an image set to the background of the  again with CSS. This would be 1000px wide and act as the content area, and is centred in the page with magin:auto. Then to the right of that there is the third segment, which is essentially the same as the first just with the 2nd colour as its background. This way, the left and right segments would stretch while the central one (which actually contains the gradient) will stay the same.

This theory is portrayed graphically [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17610534/html_css_design_prob_stackoverflow.jpg).

My problem is in regards to the two side areas. As mentioned, the central image is a fixed 1000px, but how can I have the left and right areas to have a fluid width (fixed height), but only so the left is from the left side of the browser to the central div, and the right from the right side of the div to the right side of the browser?

I hope I have explained the problem clearly enough, if not please say and I'll try and provide more information.

Cheers

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know any thing else you want.

Comment: Dear If any thing else you want please specify. If my answer is correct please accept it. People might get help from answer in future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Same question and i gave the answer on [Positioning an images outside of the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732420/positioning-an-images-outside-of-the-layout/9733197#9733197)

See the below fiddle for output...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/4/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/4/embedded/result/

**Updated fiddle as per user908041 requirement**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/5/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j6G/5/embedded/result/

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this doesn't solve the problem. I'm trying to achieve a fixed content area with fluid left & right. What you have put forward is entirely fixed.

Comment: Dear left and right are fluid columns only the image in red color is set no-repeat thats why you are thinking that its fixed.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I was looking at it the wrong way entirely. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/2MEhA/). Hope it helps.

You just need to put your gradient in a container. Than you can set up the columns inside.

EDIT:

Here the edit for 100% width: http://jsfiddle.net/2MEhA/2/

Comment: Thanks very much, but after skimming over the code, surely this wouldn't be fluid? It seems to be entirely based on fixed widths.

Comment: Once again, thank you, but after skimming over the code again, this seems to use a fluid central column rather than the sides. For me, this wouldn't make it possible to use an image. Hence why I discussed having fluid left/right columns. Is this possible?

Comment: Than you can style the .center div with text-align: center if you wish.